# select from multiple table?

Tags: php, mysqli-multi-query

I have two table as below

persons:

```
ID , FNAME, LNAME ,GENDER

100 , A , B , M
```

images:

```
IMG_D,IMG_NM,ID_PERSONS

10 , 1.JPG  , 100
20 , 2.JPG  , 100
30 , 3.JPG  , 100
```

the question is:
I WANT QUERY RETRIEVE ALL COLUMNS FROM table persons and only IMG_NM FROM table IMAGES  WITHOUT  REST OF COLUMNS IN TABLE IMAGES

I MAKE QUERY AS BELOW

```
SELECT ID,FNAME,LNAME,GENDER,IMG_NM FROM persons,images where ID= ID_PERSONS  GROUP BY ID
```

the result:

```
100 , A , B , M , 1.JPG
```

AND I WANT SHOW ALL IMAGES  WITHOUT REPEATING REST OF COLUMNS LIKE THAT

```
ID , FNAME, LNAME ,GENDER,IMG_NM

100 , A , B , M ,1.JPG
                ,2.JPG
                ,3.JPG
```

Comment: Handle custom display related things in application code. Dont complicate this at MySQL end; let it return a tabular data only. Remove `GROUP BY ID` from your sql. and then modify the result set in php

Answer (score 0):

SELECT p.ID, p.FNAME, p.LNAME, p.GENDER, GROUP_CONCAT(i.IMG_NM) AS IMG_NM FROM persons p JOIN images i ON i.ID_PERSONS = p.id GROUP BY p.id;

Should handle what you're wanting nicely.

Comment: thank you sir for response>>>it gives Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tesst\data.php on line 18

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tesst\data.php on line 31>>can you help me with this error......I appreciate your effort ...thanks again

Comment: right, there's a bug in your php code that you've not posted.  Basically you're doing the mysqli_query() wrong, and then since it's not running correctly you're doing a fetch_array against nothing which is the other error.

Comment: that's correct i found the problem and its display only one blank image and didnt display the rest of images....